# Tkinter module error on attributes like Tk or Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i am trying to use Tkinter on python 3.6

However it gives me an error when i try to run the following code:

```
import tkinter
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.mainloop()
```

The error says:

```
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'
```

I receive the same error if i try to call the attribute Frame.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: did you name your file "tkinter", or have some other file in your path named "tkinter.py"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you didn't name the file `tkinter.py`; It prevents import of `tkinter` module because the file your wrote searched first and imported.

Rename the file, and also make sure there's no `tkinter.pyc` remained.

Comment: I use Windows. I didn't save the file as  .pyc

Comment: @Vincenzo, `.pyc` is generated once you import the `.py` module.

Comment: how should it be saved then? Cheers

Comment: @Vincenzo, What do you mean `it`?

Comment: i found the problem, In Pycharm I saved the file as tkinter. How did you know that the file name was the problem?@falsetru

Comment: @Vincenzo, Because I had a similar problem when I learned & experimented `import` statement, (not with `tkinter`, but with `test` module).